# Highcharts do not hold all the values of stacked columns chart with data time axes

Tags: highcharts

I got trouble, on right and left side of charts missing few series.More precisely 1,2,11,12 series. An even if they appear i need to set some padding for the most left and right columns.

Here is my example: //jsfiddle.net/Hideon/d76zhmo0/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is reported on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts and marked as a bug.

To workaround manually set `pointRange`:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        pointRange: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8n9h7tcj/